# Change event not working on multiple select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My change event is not firing on a multiple select input. I would like an event to fire each time the multiple select's value is changed.

**HTML:**

```
<select style='width: 361px;' multiple="multiple" class='multiselect-status'>
  <option>Pending</option>
  <option>Approved</option>
  <option>Deducted</option>
  <option>Not Approved</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$("body").on('change', 'select.multiselect-status', function(e){

  console.log($(this).val());

});
```

Any ideas why this isn't firing? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The HTML is being loaded via jquery's load() function, if it make's a difference.

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/2c3vg/

Comment: try looking at your console for any error ..

Comment: It works but you need to bind handler once BODY is available in DOM or use document instead

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T4QUS/

Comment: Is your code surrounded with jquery `ready()`?

Comment: The fiddles seem to indicate the problem lies elsewhere (since it's working in those links!). I am loading the HTML dynamically via a load() function. Could that affect it?

Comment: @Andrew just set your code in document ready handler or just before </body> closing tag, problem solved...

Comment: @A.Wolff: My code is wrapped in ``$(function () { ... snippet ... })``

Comment: So you are already using ready handler and your issue comes from somewhere else, check your console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind change event either on dom ready or while you are loading your html -

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on('change', 'select.multiselect-status', function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Or

```
$('#something').load('something.html',function(){
  $("select.multiselect-status").on('change', function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.multiselect-status").on('change',  function(e){

  console.log($(this).val());

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a5rNV/