# Sharepoint Multiple Value Lookup Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, multiple-value

I hope someone can help me out here.

I have a SharePoint list with a Choice type lookup field.

I'm able to retrieve the selected value with the code below.

```js
$("select[title='My field name']").change(function() 
     { 
    alert($(this).val());
 } );
```

However this won't work when the field is set to "Allow multiple value".

If this options is enabled instead of the drop-down box an add/remove option is displayed. How can I get the selected value in this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The change function is not getting fired when using multiple values Lookup field.
Try to use "dblclick" event :

```
$('select[Title = "SelectTitle"] option').dblclick(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .dblclick() called." );
});
```

otherwise, you can add a click event to the "Add" button.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code.

`$(this).options[$(this).selectedIndex].value`

Comment: It seems like the change function is not being fired once the "allow multiple values" are enabled.

Comment: see [Change event not working on multiple select input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21764099/5090771)